# xsl: decision value from element to attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to use XSL to convert XML to another XML

The input xml contains the following element

```
<ViewSideIndicator>0</ViewSideIndicator>
```

which need to be converted to the following

```
<ImageViewDetail ViewSideIndicator="Front"/>
```

in the input file, if the value is "0", then it should be "Front" in the output
and if the value is "1", then it should be "Back" in the output

I know that we can use `<xsl:choose>` to make the value based on a decision, but i'm not sure how to do it for this case.

Comment: There does `ImageViewDetail` (element name), and part of attribute value which says "Gray", come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template (assuming that the current source context is the `ViewSideIndicator` element):

```
<ImageViewDetail>
    <xsl:attribute name="ViewSideIndicator">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="text()='0'">Front</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="text()='1'">Back</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
</ImageViewDetail>
```

Comment: +1. Better yet, use `(. = 0)` and `(. = 1)` for comparisons - it's both shorter, and will correctly handle any number representation (e.g. `00` and `01`), which is likely to be what is wanted here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this (or a version of it as a template)?

```
<ImageViewDetail>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ViewSideIndicator=0">
            <xsl:attribute name="ViewSideIndicator">Front Gray</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:attribute name="ViewSideIndicator">Back Gray</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</ImageViewDetail>
```